# Passing uri segment variable from one function to another in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Hi looking for some help. I recently started coding with Codeigniter.

I have 2 functions within the same controller. I need 'uri segment' from first function to second. Tried to google but no success.

Here is my controller:

```
public item_page() {
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $this->load->view('view');
}

public validation() {
    // Form Validation Goes Here
    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->session->set_userdata('validation_errors', validation_errors());
        redirect('item-page/'.$id); // I need variable here
    } else {
    redirect('execute');
    }
}
```

Comment: You have know form validation set_rules http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#setting-validation-rules and one you have set rules look at http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#changing-the-error-delimiters

Comment: Thanks.I do have validation but I didn't mention them here.. Sadly I dropped the idea of redirecting it to where I need $id.. Now I am redirecting it to normal function (without $id)

Comment: Did you configure your routes.php for redirect Example `$route['item-page/(:any)'] = 'item-page/index/$1';`

Comment: No... I had it once but I have slashed it out like this now.. `//$route['property/(:num)'] = 'listing/property_id_$1';`.. And ita a different url altogether..

Comment: This is good http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Comment: I have discovered something which worked for me somehow but one problem.. If I do `$this->validation($id);` in first function and `public function validation($id) { print_r($id);die;`.. This way I am able to echo the id value.. But my problem is as it shows from the code that query executes from first function itself..

Answer (score 0):

you can some Attribute in your class(controller)

controller:

```
private $page_id;

public item_page() {
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $this->page_id=$id;
    $this->load->view('view');
}

public validation() {
    // Form Validation Goes Here
    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->session->set_userdata('validation_errors', validation_errors());
        redirect('item-page/'.$this->page_id); // I need variable here
    } else {
    redirect('execute');
    }
}
```

//////
Method 2:

```
public item_page() {
        $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $this -> session -> set_userdata('id', $id);
        $this->load->view('view');
    }

    public validation() {
        // Form Validation Goes Here
        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $this->session->set_userdata('validation_errors', validation_errors());
            redirect('item-page/'.$this -> session -> userdata("id")); // I need variable here
        } else {
        redirect('execute');
        }
    }
```

hope this help.

Comment: Thanks @Mohsen Shakibafar.. Unfortunately it didn't work.. When I checked it in second function by `var_dump($this->page_id);die;` it said 'NULL'.. Any Idea Why?

Comment: hmmm :) , you can use session too , but im trying to find something else

Comment: did you try to get id from url?

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with my code here.. It shows "images" when I echo it.. may be its taking other userdata in account as I am using `if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')){` too

Comment: echo $this -> session -> userdata("id"); in your second function , and let me what you see.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101506/discussion-between-codeigniter-learner-and-mohsen-shakibafar).

Comment: set new name for it like ppId: like this :$this -> session -> set_userdata('ppid', $id); in your first method , and sec method $this -> session -> userdata("ppid");, must be fix

Comment: Sadly it doesnt echo anything then.. And var_dump say null